# set array of byts to json.RawMessage

Tags: json, go, byte

I have array of bytes in golang:

```
obj_data, _ := json.Marshal(obj)
```

And a want set this array of bytes into json.RawMessage
I thought that it would work:

```
data := json.RawMessage{obj_data}
```

but i have error:

```
cannot use obj_data (type []byte) as type byte in array element
```

please help me! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions), not a literal:

```
data := json.RawMessage(obj_data)
```